# Creating frequency plot from weblogo with frequency unit on the Y axis

Tags: sequence-alignment, motifs

Hello I am trying to create frequency plot for a motif with frequency unit on the Y axis from 0 -100 nt as the unit as represented in this paper.([Seiler et al.,](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/29457796) 2018)

[image]

Comment: Hi @Aishwarya welcome to the site. Did you look at other questions in the site or elsewhere about making motifs? What have you tried? Which concrete problem do you have following them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Within weblogo, add the `--units probability` argument and edit the figure with Illustrator (PDF/SVG) or Inkscape (SVG) to modify the y-axis, changing fractional probability (`[0,1]`) to a percentage (`[0,100]`) by multiplying by 100. Refer to the [manual](http://weblogo.threeplusone.com/manual.html#CLI) for more detail.